# Convert vga to HDMI

Tags: hdmi, vga

I have a VGA female port on my laptop. Can I get a converter which will allow me to connect a HDMI cable to my monitor?

Searching on Amazon [yields these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_12?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=vga%20port%20to%20hdmi%20lead&sprefix=vga+port+to+%2Caps%2C163&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Avga%20port%20to%20hdmi%20lead)

These don't seem to offer what I want ?
Is this possible and if so will the output quality on monitor be HDMI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not trivial. You will need an actual active converter rather than a cheap cable. The reason for this is that HDMI is digital only, and the old VGA signal is analog.

As to the quality, that depends on the output on your VGA/DB15 plug and on the quality of the convertor. I looked before and I could not find any limitation in the VGA standard. However most VGA cards come woth a 400MHz DAC which would commonly limit it to any configuration using a lower than 400MHz bandwidth.  (E.g. 2048x1536@85Hz which needs 388 MHz bandwidth). If your DAC is less capable or there are other limits then the maximum resolution will be lower.

Answer (score 0):

VGA is analog, HDMI is digital, so there can be no direct conversion. Even chaining `VGA -> DVI -> HDMI` will not work.

Here is [Tomshardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/287147-33-hdmi-make-possible) forum thread about subject. There are links to devices which can somehow do this.

Offered solution is an active element receiving VGA signal, processing it and outputting HDMI signal. Following are examples of those devices:

[Device 1](http://www.startech.com/item/VGAHD2HDMI-VGA-HD-with-Audio-to-HDMI-Format-Converter.aspx)

[Device 2](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011404&p_id=4629&seq=1&format=2)

[Device 3](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011404&p_id=6191&seq=1&format=2)

Comment: To quote part of those pages on Tom Hardware (prevents link rot):  "Yes, but the converter will need to **actively process the analog signal** from your VGA source and output a digital signal."

Comment: @Hennes, you are right, I am not trying to say something else. This is one of few possible ways to achieve VGA -> HDMI conversion.

Comment: @Nikolay - So say that in your answer, don't allow the thread which might die, say it.